# Access VBA - compare records from tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two tables that I wish to compare records  - based on a field values. Here is what I tried :

```
 Dim RCount As Long

    Dim Rst As Recordset
    Dim Rst1 As Recordset
    Dim f As Field

    'Current Record set
    Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1")
    Set Rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table2")

    With Rst

    For Each f In Rst1.Fields

    RCount = DCount("FieldFromTable1", "Table1", "[FieldFromTable1]='" & Me.[FieldFromTable2].Value & "'")

    If RCount > 0 Then
           Me.Checkbox1.Value = True
    End If

     Next f

    End With

    Rst.Close
    Rst1.Close
```

Here is my updated question, something like that I'm trying to accomplish. But still this code cycles only through currently selected record in my Table2 form.

Comment: This code appears to be only comparing the first record in `table1` with the `FieldFromTable2`. Is that what your intention is? or are you trying to see if it `fieldfromTable2` exists in `table1`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to see If FieldFormTable2.Value exists in Table1. Do I have open recordset for Table2 too, and then compare ? FieldFromTable2 is basically control on continous form, from Table2 recordset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really consider an option to just UPDATE records in tables. Thsi is what It worked for me. I was just trying to set Checkbox to TRUE when record from Table1 meets criteria in Table2. A simple UPDATE solved the problem:

```
Dim SQL As String

niz = " UPDATE Table2" & _
      " INNER JOIN Table1" & _
      " ON Table1.FieldFromTable1=Table2.FieldFromTable2" & _
      " SET Table2.Checkbox1=True"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

DoCmd.RunSQL niz
DoCmd.Requery
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment. You can use recordcounts to see if there is a record that exists and matches. You could use the following query to see if a record exists:

```vb
dim rst as recordset
dim varSQL as string

varSQL = "SELECT [fieldfromtable1] FROM Table1 WHERE [fieldfromtable1] ='" & [fieldfromtable2].value & "'"

Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(varSQL)

  If rst.recordcount = 1 then
   MsgBox "Fields have matching values !"
  End If
rst.close
```

You could replace the `=1` with `>0`.

Alternatively, I think you can use dcount() function which would be something like:

```vb
dim RCount as long

Rcount = dcount("fieldFromTable1","table1", "[fieldFromTable1]='" & me.[FieldFromTable2].value & "'")

if Rcount > 0 then
       MsgBox "Fields have matching values !"
end if
```

again, you can use `>0` or `=1` im not sure which is most appropriate for your situation.

> Edit

the following query can be performed to update the checkbox, but this isn't at form level

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.[fieldfromtable1] = table2.[fieldfromtable2] SET table1.[checkboxField] = True
WHERE table2.[fieldfromtable2]= table1.[fieldFromtable1]
```

Comment: Thanks @LiamH, but I'm getting "Data type mismatch  in criteria expresion" error. Something is wrong with my forms or Tables, because both of your codes work in my sample DB. What could be the cause ?

Comment: what are `[fieldFromTable1]` and `[fieldfromtable2]`, are they strings /numbers /dates etc. ?

Comment: Both fields are Text data type

Comment: Ive edited my answer, notice how I have encapsulated the form `'string'` with single quotes (apostrophes)

Comment: Great, It works, but I'm still missing one thing. I have to loop through all records, curently code works only for current record. What I'm trying to accomplish is basically set Checkbox to True in all records that meets the criteria.

Comment: This code will only compare the current form record (of table 2) to all the records in `table1`. if you want to set a checkbox that meets the criteria then I think you need to run an update query instead.

Comment: I don't know, but It works for curent record, checkbox is checked. Can't It be done to cycle through all records, with same code ?

Comment: I think this is moving in to a different question from the original. However if I understand correctly, you can cycle through the form and select the checkbox using vba. Or an easier method would be to update the table behind the form (table2) using an update query.

Comment: Check my updated question, this is what I'm trying to achieve. I don't know If Update would be better and easier, I haven't considered that.

Comment: you were right, UPDATE is much easier and It works just fine. Thanks for guiding me to right path.